# Cannot access to my module nested dependency in android

Tags: android, module, dependencies

I create an android module that has class dependencies like below :

```
implementation 'com.squareup.moshi:moshi:1.5.0'
implementation 'com.neovisionaries:nv-websocket-client:2.3'
```

I added this module to my project. when I want to use it, it says that 'can not access to com.neovisionaries.Adapter'.

> 1 -Why it cannot access because I think that my Async class calls the method in the background?
>
> 2-Should I add that dependency to my project?

**My Module class**

```
public class Async extends WebSocketAdapter {
   ....
public Async() {
}

public static Async getInstance(Context context) {
    if (instance == null) {
        sharedPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences(AsyncConstant.Constants.PREFERENCE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        moshi = new Moshi.Builder().build();
        instance = new Async();
    }
    return instance;
}


public void webSocketConnect(String socketServerAddress, final String appId) {
        WebSocketFactory webSocketFactory = new WebSocketFactory();
        webSocketFactory.setVerifyHostname(false);
        setAppId(appId);
        setServerAddress(socketServerAddress);
        try {
            webSocket = webSocketFactory
                    .setConnectionTimeout(TIMEOUT)
                    .createSocket(socketServerAddress)
                    .addListener(this);
            webSocket.connectAsynchronously();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }}
```

**MyPresenter class**

```
public class SocketPresenter implements SocketContract.presenter {

private Async async;
private SocketContract.view view;
@Override
    public void connect(String socketServerAddress, String appId) {
        async.webSocketConnect(socketServerAddress, appId);
    }
```

this line has an error `async.webSocketConnect(socketServerAddress, appId);` that says `websocketConnect` can not acces to my neseted module dependecy.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When Gradle `compile` keyword has been deprecated, it was replaced by two new keywords: `implementation` and `api`. The `implementation` keyword keeps your dependencies internal while `api` exposes them like the old `compile` keyword did. Therefore, you should use `api` instead of `implementation`.

See more details in the [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html).

Comment: Happy to help :)

Comment: @SirCodesalot Module has other dependencies(like **api ('io.socket:socket.io-client:1.0.0'**)) and that module is uploaded on Bintray. After upload successfully I got a maven dependency like this **implementation 'com.sample.mysdk:1.5.0'**. But when I am using this dependency then I am not getting nested dependency class.